# adding extra identifiers to dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of menu items in a list format like so

```
<ul class="menu unselectable">
    <li class="group">
        Group Title
        <ul>
            <li class="groupItem i0">item 0</li>
            <li class="groupItem i1 over">item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="group">
        Another Group Title
        <ul>
            <li class="groupItem i2">item 2</li>
            <li class="groupItem i1">item 1 (if I hover here, the others should too</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The idea is, if I hover on one item with class `i1` then all `i1` items should behave the same. So I thought of adding a class `over` to all `i1` items when I hover on any of them like so.

```
$(".groupItem").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("over");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
);
```

The problem is I can't think of a way to identify what item has just been hovered on aside from `$(this)`. To remedy this I thought of adding `i1` as an `id` to items, but different dom nodes shouldn't have the same `id`. My next idea was to add the attribute `value` to the `li` items but to no avail (when I did a quick test with `$(this).val()` kept returning 0 regardless of the `value` actually stored in the node.

Is there any way I can add an identifier so I can just say `$(this).<someIdentifier>` , and target all the dom nodes with that identifier?

Comment: Can't you just figure out what have been hovered over using `$(".over")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add an attribute `groupID="{id}"` and then call `$(this).attr('groupID')`

Comment: Or use an HTML5 "data-groupID" attribute and access the value with ".data('groupID')" ...

Comment: You can generally add any arbitrary attribute, so this should work, but if you're going to do it, might as well use documented (and supported in HTML5) data attributes which are just prefixed with "data-" like this: `data-groupID="{id}"`

Comment: Keep in mind that arbitrary attributes are not supported on all legacy browsers, mind you.

Comment: lol I have not problem cutting anyone with a legacy browser off. They shouldn't be allowed on the internet @GregPettit :D

Answer (score 2):

```
Element.prototype.secondId = '';
```

and than

```
document.getElementById('id5').secondId = 13;
```

As this you just set on any element a new property which you can use as you wish but is just in javascript not in html.

Comment: That works too, but I have to say @Daniel 's is a bit more elegant. Thanks Khael

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend adding false attributes to elements, and this will work even if data attributes are not well supported by the user's browser:

```
$(".groupItem").hover(
    function () {
        var className = this.className.split(' ')[1];
        $('.' + className).addClass("over");
    },
    function () {
        var className = this.className.split(' ')[1];
        $('.' + className).removeClass("over");
    }
);
```

NOTE: Requires that classes are always organized as you specified above. A safer way could be:

```
var className = $.trim(this.className.replace('groupItem',''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).filter('#selector')
```

Comment: Sorry that's not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for everything though @vmex151 cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please, Try working below code as below once:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.menu{ display:inline;}
.menu li{ display:inline; float: left;width: 100px;}
.menu li ul{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".group").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find("ul").show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find("ul").hide();
    }
    ); 
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="group">
        Group Title
        <ul>
            <li>GT 1</li>
            <li>GT 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="group">
        Trochlear Nerve
        <ul>
            <li>TN 1</li>
            <li>TN 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank's for all your efforts @Umesh I'm really sorry if my question was misleading, but that's not exactly what I had in mind. I'll try to word my question better next time. Cheers